# Am I missing the similar questions bar on the right?

Tags: discussion, support, related-questions

I just posted a question and on the right I have the box for meta stuff and the blog posts, and below that hot network questions, I'm sure there used to be a similar content thing, am I mad?

It's back now, am I mad or did something change?

Comment: The "Related" column? It takes a short while to be populated, so it doesn't immediately appear, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

As written by Daniel Fischer, it takes some time for the Related questions to show up.

I'm not sure on the time this takes, and if it is a "scheduled" job, so to say.

In any case, a bit of patience will be a sufficient solution :).